# Add styles to module in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a directive and module to import directive in other modules. But how can I add *.scss files into this module to load its only when module will be required.

Example:

```
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {TooltipDirective} from "./tooltip.directive";
//import "tooltip.scss" ???
@NgModule({
              imports     : [
                  CommonModule
              ],
              declarations: [TooltipDirective],
              exports     : [TooltipDirective]
          })
export class TooltipModule {
}
```

Comment: CSS is attached to components not modules

Comment: @YounesM I know. But I don't have a component, I have only directive

Comment: You're applying your CSS to what template then ?

Comment: Tooltip create template using document.createElement. But styles for this element needs only when they are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind styles to a directive as it's template-less. If you want your styles to only apply to the element you're creating your best bet would be to use inline styles on the created element.

Also, you said you are using `document.createElement`, please don't.

Use `renderer` instead, for both the creation and the setting of the styles:

```
import {Renderer} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {}

const element = this.renderer.createElement('div');

// You might have to pass element.nativeElement here, can't remember
this.renderer.setElementStyle(element, 'background-color', 'red');
```

**EDIT:**

You said you need the tooltip to be appended to body, this is not really how you do it in angular. You don't create things on the fly most of the times. What you can do instead is create the tooltips component and then apply it to `app.component.html` and change the `app.component.ts` selector to `body`. This will cause the `AppComponent` to become the `body` tag of the document. Then I'd suggest you to build an api service for the tooltips component which can be used to trigger the tooltips on and off as well as setting other things such as texts inside the tooltips.

As I lack a full code example of what the tooltips actually does I can't give you any clearer examples of how to do this. But this should give you an idea on how to achieve what you want.

Comment: I thought about it. But I'm using sass with mixin, functions, variables ant etc. So I can't just put all my styles through renderer

Comment: @Illorian Well then you're gonna have to turn your directive into its own component.

Comment: I will do it if you help me with append template to body element not to parent element

Comment: @Illorian You do you need it to be appended to body?

Comment: @Illorian I meant why not you :p